# React enzyme not able to test click funtion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOk66.png)

this is my whole code of component in that image and test code

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import ProfileCard from '../profileCard';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import InfoCard from '../infoCard';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
});

describe('Profile Card', () => {
  const props = {
    percentageCompleted: 20,
    toggleModalVisibility: () => console.log(''),
    title: 'Value From Test',
    icon: 'string',
    active: false
  };
  const component = mount(<InfoCard {...props} />);

  it('onclick function should toggle model visibality', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<InfoCard {...props} />).instance();
    const preventDefaultSpy = jest.fn();
    expect(component.props().title.length).toBe(15);
    //wrapper.onClick  //i am stuck here
    console.log('what is in there', wrapper);
  });

  // it('should render correctly', () => {
  //   const tree = renderer.create(<InfoCard {...props} />).toJSON();
  //   expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  // });

  it('icon shpuld be equal to prop icon', () => {
    expect(component.find('img').prop('src')).toEqual(props.icon);
  });
});
```

in that i am not figuring out how can i test that onClick function. in function i am not taking argument or something to pass in funtion as a argument. so how do i test this function. sorry for my english i am little frustrated because of this.

Comment: Could be because Shallow mounting doesn't render children. [Difference between Shallow and Mount](https://gist.github.com/fokusferit/e4558d384e4e9cab95d04e5f35d4f913) Have you tried targeting the button to trigger a click event?

Comment: onClick is function please check image of my component that is covarage report from jest --coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I apologize as I only know how to develop in React Functions. But here is a MVP to test `onClick` functionality. You're simply just needing to assert on `toggleModalVisibility` and `title`.

You'll need to mock out the `toggleModalVisibility`, then find the element(in your case the `div`) and perform a simulate event(`click`) and do your assertions there. You don't need to worry about the implementation details in that class file since it doesn't matter, you only care about the expected output.

```
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import InfoCard from "../src/InfoCard";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const toggleModalVisibility = jest.fn();

const initialProps = {
  toggleModalVisibility,
  title: "My title",
  active: true
};
const getInfoCard = () => {
  return shallow(<InfoCard {...initialProps} />);
};

let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  toggleModalVisibility.mockClear();
});
it("should call toggleModalVisiblity when onClick", () => {
  wrapper = getInfoCard();

  wrapper.find("div#myDiv").simulate("click");

  expect(toggleModalVisibility).toHaveBeenCalledWith(initialProps.title);
});
```

[image: Edit React Jest and Enzyme Testing]

Comment: see the function name is onClick there. thanks for the nice explaination it's helpfull

Comment: Yes, your functions name in `InfoCard` is called `onClick` but that doesn't matter. You should assert on the output of that method, therefore you care essentially testing `onClick`. If you go to the CodeSandBox link you'll see the MVP.

Comment: The test in the code sand box is passing. Are you talking about your written enzyme test?'

Comment: thanks it worked problem was i wasnt able to access wrapper.instance(); i canged approach to how you suggest thanks